# How to select the active cell if it has a value not the formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In Range ("A2:A10") I have a vlookup equation.
I want to select the active cell in that range, if it has a value and ignore the other cells with the formula in the same range

Comment: Can you explain with sample data?

Comment: How to select an already active cell? Please, better explain what you want doing. Are you talking about a range? Do you have 'a vlookup equation' in the mentioner range? If 'equation' means formula and in that range you have it, where the non formula cell to be searched for?

Answer (score 0):

This will `Select` the first cell in the range that does not have a formula:

```
Sub FindValue()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Range("A2:A10")
    For Each r In rng
        If r.HasFormula Then
        Else
            r.Select
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

If all the cells in the range have formulas, `Selection` is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

If in range "A2:A10" you have formulas, **but also cells without any formula**, you can put the last one category in another range in this way:

```
   Dim rng As Range, c As Range
   Set rng = Range("A2:A10")
   Set rng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) 'only cells without formula
   For Each c In rng.cells
        c.Select
        Debug.Print c.Address 'if you want the first one, put here Exit For
   Next
```

If no cells without formula, the above code will raise an error. It can be caught with some error handling, but I only tried showing a shor way of doing it.